# Runtime Error in C

Tags: c, runtime

I am trying to solve a interest problem.
Why is this code Giving Runtime error?
I Cannot figure out any reason. Is it because of the use of float?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    float c,temp,temp2,x;
    float r;
    int n,ans;
    scanf("%f",&c);
    if(c>0 )
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n>0)
        {
            scanf("%f",&r);
            if(r>=0)
            {
                temp=n;
                temp2=c;
                while(temp>0)
                {
                    x=c*1200/(1200+r);
                    c=temp2+x;
                    temp--;
                }
                ans=(int)x;
                printf("%d\n",ans);
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What error? Where, description?

Comment: I am Using an online gcc compiler (GCC-4.9.2) . It is just saying Runtime error.

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: try `return 1;` --> `return 0;`

Comment: `c=6000 n=3 r=12' . It gives me desired output along with Runtime Error.

Comment: What @BLUEPIXY said. Plus, for  some inputs it may result in division by zero.

Comment: @MandarBhamare  Well I am not getting any error with the input you specified.

Comment: @MandarBhamare Do you understand why?

Comment: Not really. @EugeneSh.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) then.

Comment: What is the input and what output do you get _exactly_ ?

Comment: @MandarBhamare, please paste the error you are getting and the command you are executing. Because I successfully executed this program in my system. I didn't get any error for `c=6000 n=3 r=12`; I get the o/p `17645`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. what inputs can cause a divide by zero? The only divide I see is by (1200+r) where the OP has specifically checked that r>=0

Comment: @FredK True. Missed the check.

Comment: @Pawan It was tested on an online server. The code worked fine for some of my test cases too. Just changing `return1` to `return 0` solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try return 0;

at the end...and it should work

Though ,I don`t know why returning more than 0 gives problem for online compiler..
It should work even with returning any int value.

Comment: Even for Netbeans `return 1` runs the problem without any problem. But on closing the output terminal , output window says **RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 9s)**